# Split record in SQL Server with ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have such a problem. I need to separate sentences from a column of words as in tables. How to do it?

```
--I have table #Keywords like this:
CREATE TABLE #Keywords 
(
    Word nvarchar(400),
    Id int
)

INSERT INTO #Keywords VALUES ('some text1 to spliting', 1);
INSERT INTO #Keywords VALUES ('some text2 to spliting', 2);
INSERT INTO #Keywords VALUES ('some text3 to spliting', 3);

SELECT * FROM #Keywords

-- In result I want table like this:
CREATE TABLE #KeywordsResult 
(
    Word nvarchar(400),
    Id int
)

INSERT INTO #KeywordsResult VALUES ('some', 1);
INSERT INTO #KeywordsResult VALUES ('text1', 1);
INSERT INTO #KeywordsResult VALUES ('to', 1);
INSERT INTO #KeywordsResult VALUES ('spliting', 1);
INSERT INTO #KeywordsResult VALUES ('some', 2);
INSERT INTO #KeywordsResult VALUES ('text2', 2);
INSERT INTO #KeywordsResult VALUES ('to', 2);
INSERT INTO #KeywordsResult VALUES ('spliting', 2);
INSERT INTO #KeywordsResult VALUES ('some', 3);
INSERT INTO #KeywordsResult VALUES ('text3', 3);
INSERT INTO #KeywordsResult VALUES ('to', 3);
INSERT INTO #KeywordsResult VALUES ('spliting', 3);

SELECT * FROM #KeywordsResult
```

Comment: Why don't you do that in AP?

Comment: [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [T-SQL split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `string_split` is super-easy:

```
select * from [#Keywords] k
cross apply string_split(k.[Word], ' ')
```

Comment: Great thanks, it works!